# TeXstudio Does Not Recognize Local TeX Live (2023) Installation

Tags: texlive, texstudio, linux

I recently installed TeX Live 2023 on *Ubuntu 22.04* following "[The TeX Live Guide—2023](https://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable)" in my local home directory. While I can compile documents using pdflatex on the terminal without any issues, TeXstudio, when attempting the same task, defaults to the distro TeX Live installation (ver. 2021). I removed TeXstudio, reinstalled it, and the issue persists.

I modified my .bashrc paths to point to the new TeX Live installation directory.

```
$ whereis latex
latex: /usr/bin/latex /home/user/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/latex /usr/share/man/man1/latex.1.gz
```

Pdflatex :

```
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023)
kpathsea version 6.3.5
...
Compiled with libpng 1.6.39; using libpng 1.6.39
Compiled with zlib 1.2.13; using zlib 1.2.13
Compiled with xpdf version 4.04
```

TeXstudio :

```
$ texstudio --version 
TeXstudio 4.6.3 (0.0.0++)
$ whereis texstudio
texstudio: /usr/bin/texstudio /usr/share/texstudio
```

Update : running TeXstudio with this option solves the issue :

```
texstudio --texpath /your_path/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/latex
```

But editing the launcher, under Xfce environment, with the same command doesn't work.

Comment: do you start the editor from your desktop, that may not be running in a shell started from your bashrc

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I usually don't install texlive along the distro's texlive installation. But since there might be dependencies to other packages, I install texlive-dummy packages instead. 

This must be done manually. If you're interested, I can write an answer outlining the process.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes I edited the *.desktop launcher with this command but it doesn't work

Comment: @Mensch Welcome too I'm very pleased to contribute

Comment: @Wamseln Sure my friend If you have better solution go on !

Comment: your whereis shows a bad result. You have installed a texlive 2023 from tug but you are not using it, you are using the (probably older) system tex that came with your linux: `

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu the recommended packages for `texstudio` are (`apt info texstudio`):

> Recommends: adwaita-qt, texlive-base, texlive-latex-base, texlive-latex-recommended, texstudio-doc, texstudio-l10n

This means, that they get installed as well by default, if `texstudio` is installed via `apt`. If `texlive` is installed manually, the packages `texlive-base, texlive-latex-base, texlive-latex-recommended` are not welcome, as they would be redundant and likely out-of-date.

In order to circumvent this, it is necessary to install a "dummy" package, that tells the package manager, that the recommended dependencies are already satisfied. (That has to be done prior to installing `texstudio`.) That is specifically what the `equivs` package is for. `equivs` takes a text-file, that contains dependency infos and creates a package out of these dependencies. If this package is then installed, the package managers knows, that all the dependencies from the text-file are satisfied via the just installed package.

Thankfully the text-file needed to build the required package for satisfying the texlive dependcies, is provided by the tex user group. Take a look at this text-file for vanilla texlive 2023: [debian-equivs-2023-ex.txt](https://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2023-ex.txt). If you inspect it carefully, the structure and the purpose of this text-file are quite clear.

I will only go over the necessary steps in order to create and install the dummy package. If you want to know more, there is a more in depth explanation  in the debian wiki [here](https://wiki.debian.org/TeXLive). The writers of this article point out, that strictly this method requires a system wide installation of vanilla `texlive` as root, as (I guess) otherwise other users of your system will be no longer able to install the distro's texlive-packages. But as long, as you are the only user of `TeX` on your system, that's not a problem.

Now: To build the dummy-packages, some other packages are needed: `equivs`, `tex-common`, `texinfo`, `perl-tk`, `perl-doc`, `freeglut3`. They can be installed via:

```
sudo apt install tex-common texinfo equivs perl-tk perl-doc freeglut3
```

If this is done, all that is needed, is:

1. use `equivs` to create the dummy package
2. install the dummy package
3. clean the temporary files

**1. use `equivs` to create the package**

create temporary directory:

```
sudo mkdir /tmp/tl-equivs
```

cd into directory:

```
cd /tmp/tl-equivs
```

download text-file for equivs (change texlive version accordingly):

```
sudo wget https://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2023-ex.txt
```

build the package with equivs (change texlive version accordingly):

```
sudo equivs-build debian-equivs-2023-ex.txt
```

**2. install the package**

while still in the temp directory:

```
sudo dpkg -i texlive-local_*_all.deb
```

**3. clean up**

As we build everything in `/tmp/` cleanup is not necessary as the system will handle it for us.

I hope this helps!